# Android animate marker position in google maps while using clustering

Tags: android, google-maps

I am adding marker to google maps by using clustering

```
private ClusterManager<MyMarkerTest> mClusterManager;

mClusterManager.addItem(new MyMarkerTest(lat, longitude));
```

Here is my `MyMarkerTest` class

```
public class MyMarkerTest implements ClusterItem {


    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public MyMarkerTest(double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Upon some response from web service I want to change the position of marker, I can remove and add again, but all I want to do is animate the marker to new position.

In my gradle  I have added

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
```